# .composer/config file permission denied using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php, virtualbox

I have a laravel project on an ubuntu virtualbox.
I used to run `composer update` and all worked fine. I don't know of any changes that could have affected this but now when I run `composer update` I get

`file_get_contents(/home/user/.composer/config.json): failed to open stream:
  Permission denied`

Does anyone know why? When I run `sudo composer update` , it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your permissions got changed somehow (perhaps not related with running `composer`). Setting the owner of that file as your user should fix the issue:

```
sudo chown user /home/user/.composer/config.json
```

The above assumes that the username is `user` from the home path. As a side note, it works when running it as a super user using `sudo` because there's no permissions restrictions in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about just `sudo chown ${USER} /home/${USER}/.composer/config.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have valid permissions for this file. Try running:

```
sudo chmod 0777 /home/user/.composer/config.json
```

**EDIT**

**Of course, you should do it only in development environment (you mentioned you use Virtualbox). You should not do it in production environment.**

Comment: While this is a valid solution, I would suggest you explain the pitfalls of giving full access to a file for any user. Because while in this case it might be used in a dev environment where it's not an issue, some people might take the advice and use it on production servers, not knowing/understanding the security risks it implies.

Comment: @Bogdan That's true, I've added info to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Run below command.

```
sudo composer update
```

Comment: it is not advisable to use sudo with `composer`: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details