# No access to .ssh/config with envoy

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-envoy

After reinstall Kubuntu I have problems with run envoy with ssh. I set 700 to config file,
but got error anyway:

```
$ sudo chmod  700  /home/serge/.ssh/config
serge@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/hostels2$ envoy run Hostels2Deploy  --app_version=0.112 --run_migration=1   --run_migration_seed=1                                                                                                   
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/serge/.ssh/config): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/serge/.composer/vendor/laravel/envoy/src/SSHConfigFile.php on line 35                                                            

Warning: file_get_contents(/home/serge/.ssh/config): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/serge/.composer/vendor/laravel/envoy/src/SSHConfigFile.php on line 35                                                                 
[laravelserver]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname laravelserver: Name or service not known                                                                                                                                                    
This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

How to fix it ?

**MODIFIED :**
It does not look like issue with envoy file, as it worked before Kubuntu reinstallation
Searching for decision I run next :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/serge/.composer/config.json
sudo chown serge /home/serge/.composer/config.json
```

But I got message that /home/serge/.composer/config.json not found. then I take it from prior home instalation with content :

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/envoy": "^1.6",
        "laravel/installer": "~1.1"
    }
}
```

and run

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

But still got this error. I have :

```
$ composer -v
...
Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17
```

Somethimg wrong with composer or its permittions, as I did not have /home/serge/.composer/config.json file?

which steps to take ?

Comment: Post your Envoy.blade.php.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [.composer/config file permission denied using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511744/composer-config-file-permission-denied-using-laravel) branch and after command :

```
 sudo chmod  744  /home/serge/.ssh/config
```

helped me !